# How to check if API is able to handle the request using PHP

Tags: php, api

I have a PHP file calling a request to an API:

```
 $url = https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/search?query=spaghetti%bolognese&apiKey={{apikey}}3;
 $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
 $name =  $response["title"];
```

The $name should show what the json file's response's value is when the key is title.

I only have 150 requests allowed per day with my account so I am trying to only find $name when it can still make the request. No matter what I try I am still getting the following error:

> file_get_contents(https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/search?query=spaghetti%bolognese&apiKey={{apikey}}):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 402

I have tried the following but don't know where I'm going wrong. Can anyone help?

```
$url = https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/search?query=spaghetti%bolognese&apiKey={{apikey}}3;
if(file_get_contents($url), true) {
    $name =  $response["title"];
}
```

Comment: I would expect something like `$url = "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/search?query=spaghetti%bolognese&apiKey={$apikey}"`; where `$apikey` is the key you have for the API.

Comment: I have the "" I just accidentally removed them when I was removing the real apikey